# Create a Drupal view with a list of top voted nodes by month

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-fivestar, drupal-modules

I'm using the Drupal 6 Views module to request for top nodes rated using the fivestar module. However, I can't seem to find out how I can create a view to request for the top voted node for each month and display them on a list.

What I'd like as a result is a list like this:

- January 2011: Most voted node title an link to that node
- December 2010: Most voted node title an link to that node
- November 2010: Most voted node title an link to that node
- ...

I'm not even sure this is possible using Views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up your view with the voting relationship. 
(more info here http://www.lullabot.com/videos/building-views-fivestar-and-votingapi)

Make sure you sort by vote result descending. 
According to your example above, just add the Node Title field and checkmark "link this field to its node".

Secondly, you need to group your listing based on a date value.

1. Add the field node post date. Checkmark Exclude from Display. Set the date format to Custom value of "F Y" (That is "Month Year" i.e. Jannuary 2011)
2. Views out of the box does not support limiting each group to a certain number, so you need to download the "Views Limit Grouping" module (search for it on drupal.org)
3. Once installed, change the views Style to "Grouping Field" and limit items to 1.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Very nice suggestion, thanks. I ended up doing it differently: I created 2 views with a post date argument. When the first one is called without argument, I display the "Summary, sorted descending". Now I created a new theme override file called "views-view-summary--VIEWNAME.tpl.php" where I display the other view between each summary item by calling the views_embed_view() method.