# Drupal 7: How to show the top rated nodes of the day/week/month?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm building a site in Drupal seven. Its main purpose it's to get feeds from about 300 blogs, and show the posts in a organized way. I'm using the feeds module, and I'm having no problem with organizing the content with tags and categories.

However, I want to show in the main page the X top rated posts of the day/week/month, and I don't really have any clue on how to approach this. Its very important that this top rated nodes have his own rss feed, so people can subscribe just to the X bests posts.

Reading other related questions, I guess showing the top rated questions is possible using a view, but I don't know how to translate (or export) this view into a RSS feed. Maybe using some short of taxonomy term? Does this make any sense?

I'm really new to drupal, and I don't have any real programming skills, so I'm wondering if this is a relatively easy way to approach this.

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

PS. Excuse my poor English :(

PS. I found this related questions:

[A Drupal view to show the top rated node per day, each day for a year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917167/a-drupal-view-to-show-the-top-rated-node-per-day-each-day-for-a-year/5921032#5921032)

[Create a Drupal view with a list of top voted nodes by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635299/create-a-drupal-view-with-a-list-of-top-voted-nodes-by-month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) display called **Feed**. Create a views display with that display.